# SignalR .Net Core 3.1 unable to send object in SendAsync method from service class

Tags: json, signalr, upgrade, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

Previously I was using .Net Core 2.2, I was able to send a json object from a service class using hub context and SendAsync method to a front end web client. Im having issues after I've upgraded my project framework to 3.1. If i call the SendAsync method using a json object, it will hit an error stating "{"**The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is not supported.**"}", if I send any other class object it will directly go to **OnDisconnected**.

Sample of the method i use

**Using Json Object**: await _hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("NotificationResponse", jsonObject);

**Using Class Object**: await _hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("NotificationResponse", notificationObject);

I've tried sending object directly from the hub, I was able to send a normal class object but not a json object. I did the testing on my project and also sample from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question on github and got the answer from BrennanConroy. Thanks alot !

His answer was:

2.1 was using Newtonsoft internally for Json, 3.1 uses System.Text.Json. If you're using features that don't work with System.Text.Json you can switch back to Newtonsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#switch-to-newtonsoftjson

After doing this it fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you reference using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson? I had to do this for the client.

Comment: @GregoryBologna for this project i was working on the backend/server part. the client solution was done by someone else but i dont think i added that as a reference